# What is the process of star formation?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, stellar-evolution

What is the process of star formation and what happens to stars after their death?

Comment: You can search the web for "star formation". Try for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_formation.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)

Comment: This is an enormous topic, but the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_evolution is a good place to start.

Comment: @gandalf61 thank you :-) I've read it.

Comment: Hello! Please try to focus more - you are currently asking multiple questions in one post. You can always [edit] your question to specify it or [ask a new one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas hi jonas, I'm sorry. I will keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of star formation (which is known as stellar evolution) changes a star over time. The mass of a star makes an impact on its lifetime. So depending on the mass, a lifetime of a star can vary from a few million years to a trillion years.

[image: Representative lifetimes of stars as a function of their masses]

All stars are formed from collapsing clouds of gas and dust, often called nebulae or molecular clouds. These very first baby stars are known as protostars. Over time, maybe million years, these protostars settle down and become main-sequence stars.

Nuclear fusion gives power to stars in their formation, evolution, and the rest of their lifetime. Initially, this power generated by a fusion of hydrogen atoms at the core of main-sequence stars. Lately, these atoms become Helium. According to the mass of the star, the process of evolution varies after this stage.

- stars like the Sun begin to fuse hydrogen along a spherical shell surrounding the core.
  This causes a gradual increase in the size of stars passing through the subgiant stage until it reaches the red giant phase of stars.

[image: A red giant]

- Stars with at least half the mass of the Sun can also begin to generate energy through the fusion of helium at their core, whereas more massive stars can fuse heavier elements along with a series of concentric shells. Once a star like the Sun has exhausted its nuclear fuel, its core collapses into a dense white dwarf and the outer layers are expelled as a planetary nebula.

[image: a white dwarf]
[image: cat's eye nebula - a planetary nebula]

*Stars with around ten or more times the mass of the Sun can explode in a supernova as their iron cores collapse into an extremely dense neutron star or black hole. The smallest red dwarfs reach the end of their existence, they will slowly become brighter and hotter before running out of hydrogen fuel and becoming low-mass white dwarfs.

[image: stellar evolution]

Comment: Hi sachini Wickramaarachchi -- please add links and citations to the images you are using since they are not your own. It's important to give credit to the original creators. Thanks!